# Multiple answers at once in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a complicated excel sheet with multiple variables to give a single output (I will name this the 'result') via multiple formula in various cells. One cell (I will name it X) can only have 60 possible entries. I would like to know what the 'result' for all 60 options while changing the variables in the other cells.

One way I have thought it could be possible is by having a table with the 60 possible entries in one column (I'll call this column A) and the 'result' in the corresponding cell in the column next to it (I'll call this column B). But I don't know how to get all the 'results', simultaneously in the other column.

I feel like it needs to be a formula like [when X = A1, B1 = 'result'] then filter this down the column.

Can anyone help?!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by two ways. By filter or pivot table. I find tutorial that can help you.

here is the filter link
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-7fbe34f4-8382-431d-942e-41e9a88f6a96

here is the pivot table link
https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html